# Enabling HTTPS for GeoNetwork 4.2.2 does not work with OAUTH2 OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, geonetwork

After successfully implemented the install of SSL certificates in the server, GeoNetwork can now be accessed through `https://domain/geonetwork`

However, when clicking on the 'Sign in' button, an error is displayed on the screen showing the following URL:

```
http://domain/geonetwork/login/oauth2/code/geonetwork-oicd
```

Note the above URL is using http instead, not https, not sure why, or if this misconfiguration is causing the OpenID Connect to fail.

So, why does the redirect URI have 'http', and not 'https'?

I have changed in the database the values for `system/server/port` and `system/server/protocol` but these ones do not seem to have any effect in the above error.

Besides, the parameter: `OPENIDCONNECT_IDTOKENROLELOCATION` not sure how to configure it, where could I find an example of this value? What is the default value that GeoNetwork uses?

Comment: Hi, I have looked in the Geonetwork docs how to redirect all traffic to httpS (I'm using the docker version) and set up certificates... I was hoping in something already available in the docker-compose.yml file as in Geonode... but no. Would you mind shed some light on the steps to follow? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here,
https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/6947#issuecomment-1950973525

The GN official docker image (v4.4.x or v4.2.x) relies on Jetty with HTTP at default port 8080. To enable HTTPS for Jetty 9.4, need to enable ssl and https modules.